# Wrapping Selectpicker with Vuejs Directive and i18n

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Somebody can help me?

I am doing a Vue.js directive to wrap the [bootstrap-selectpicker](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/) and inside the directive I would like to use the [vue-i18n-plugin](https://github.com/Haixing-Hu/vue-i18n) to translate a default title in case this parameters came empty but I can't... I am receiving an error telling that:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $i18n is not defined

**my-directive.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.directive('plSelectpicker', {
  twoWay: true,

  params: [
    'title',
    'style',
    'liveSearch',
    'actionsBox'
  ],

  bind: function() {
    $(this.el).selectpicker({
      liveSearch: this.params.title || true,
      title: this.params.title || $i18n.select,
      style: this.params.style || 'btn-white',
      actionsBox: this.params.actionsBox || true,
    });
  },
});
```

**I've tried also that one:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import i18n from 'vue-i18n-plugin/src/vue-i18n.js';
Vue.use(i18n);

Vue.directive('plSelectpicker', {
  twoWay: true,

  params: [
    'title',
    'style',
    'liveSearch',
    'actionsBox'
  ],

  bind: function() {
    $(this.el).selectpicker({
      liveSearch: this.params.title || true,
      title: this.params.title || $i18n.select, // also tried this.$i18n
      style: this.params.style || 'btn-white',
      actionsBox: this.params.actionsBox || true,
    });
  },
});
```

But it head me to the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of undefined

Somebody any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` refers to the directive, not the Vue instance, so `$i18n` isn't accessible that way.  Try `this.vm.$i18n`

Comment: Cool!! It works but I still have a problem... I when I change the language application this title does not change! Do you know why? All the app is changing but it does not!

Comment: The selectpicker title is not responsive like Vue.  You'll need to use the `update` function of the directive to update, refresh, or maybe rebuild the select picker with new options